# How to sort this array with hashes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sort an array of javascript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/how-to-sort-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

I have output that looks like this:

```
[ { value: 1, count: 1 }, { value: 2, count: 2 } ]
```

I need to iterate through hashes in the array and then return the value number which has the highest count. Seems simple but I'm a bit stumped. I've tried using a separate array to save both sets of values but I can't figure out the best way to do it.

Comment: Do you actually need to sort the array to get the element with the highest `count`? Also, is this homework?

Comment: Nope, not homework. Also you're right, I guess sorting is not the right way to describe it. I simply need the value that corresponds to the highest count

Comment: Asked a bunch of times and JavaScript does not have hashes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var a = [{
    value: 1,
    count: 1
}, {
    value: 2,
    count: 2
}, {
    value: 7,
    count: 8
}, {
    value: 5,
    count: 0
}, {
    value: 10,
    count: 3
}];

// sorting using a custom sort function to sort the 
// greatest counts to the start of the array
// take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp
// to understand how the custom sort function works
// better references can be found 
// here: http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11
// and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort
a.sort( function( v1, v2 ){
    return v2.count - v1.count;
});

for ( var i in a ) {
    console.log( a[i] );
}

// the greatest one is the first element of the array
var greatestCount = a[0];

console.log( "Greatest count: " + greatestCount.count );
```

Comment: You da man, davidbuzatto

Comment: documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort (most people prefer MDN or MSDN to w3schools)

Comment: Please don't reference w3schools. Much better to reference the relevant specification ([ECMA5](http://es5.github.com/#x15.4.4.11)) and perhaps [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) or MSDN for examples.

Comment: jbabey and RobG, thanks for your tip! I will use better references now.

Comment: @davidbuzatto:

Note the question is to return the value of the highest count.

Hence, it should be:

    greatestCount.value